# What is the recommended way in Julia to create a shared module?

Tags: import, module, julia, global-variables, using

After some experiment and searching, I figured out 2 ways of creating a shared module
that holds some constant values.

SCHEME A:

```
# in file sharedconstants.jl:
module sharedconstants
  kelvin = 273.15
end
# -------------------------


# in file main.jl:
include("./sharedconstants.jl");
using .sharedconstants
print(sharedconstants.kelvin, "\n");
# -------------------------
```

SCHEME B:

```
# in file sharedconstants.jl:
module sharedconstants
  kelvin = 273.15
end
# -------------------------


# in file main.jl:
import sharedconstants 
print(sharedconstants.kelvin, "\n");
# -------------------------
```

Scheme B does not always work and when it fails it throws
the error of not finding sharedconstants in current Path. Plus, Scheme B
requires the name of module (sharedconstants) the same as the trunk of
the file name. I wonder which way of the above is better in terms of
compiling and execution. Also is there any other approach to do the job?
I transferred from FORTRAN and I am quite used to simply
`use sharedconstants` in my code.

Comment: Be aware that every `include` of a file in different global scopes (file scope or module scope) creates a separate copy of that file's contents, it's exactly like copying and pasting lines into different documents. You're dealing with *constants*, so you could actually get away with separate copies. But there are 2 ways of sharing stuff: 1) make a module into a package; packages are only loaded once and are reused on every `using/import`, or 2) `include` your module files once each into a main script, and do relative `using/import` to share earlier modules in subsequent modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For performance reasons this should be a `const` (BTW module names use CamelNaming):

```
module SharedConstants2
    const kelvin = 273.15
end
```

Writing it this way makes it type-stable which results in huge performance difference:

```
julia> @btime sharedconstants.kelvin * 3
  18.574 ns (1 allocation: 16 bytes)
819.4499999999999

julia> @btime SharedConstants2.kelvin * 3
  0.001 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
819.4499999999999
```

Regarding the question "where to place it" I would recommend doing a Julia package - start reading here: https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/creating-packages/

Finally, you might have a look at the `PhysicalConstants.jl` package https://github.com/JuliaPhysics/PhysicalConstants.jl